# Lazy loading with CrudRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson, lazy-loading

I have a simple parent-child relation (one to many). And I am retrieving parents in two endpoints. One to get a list of parents and one to get a single parent. On the list, I don't want to serialize a list of children for each parent. I want to show a list of children only when I am getting a single parent.

I am working with spring boot and CrudRepository.
I tried

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

also `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`  and in the end, I was writing custom HQL with FETCH keyword.

Parent Model

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private List<Child> children;
```

Child Model

```
@Column(name = "parent_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Long parentId;
```

Parent Repository

```
 public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent, Long>
```

Parent Service

```
List<Parent> findAll() {
    return StreamSupport
            .stream(repository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

As I said I want to sometimes serialize a list of children in this relation and in some cases not.

Comment: What are you using for serialization?

Comment: I am just using spring boot plus Jackson for serialization.

Comment: I’m not familiar enough with Jackson to know if there is a way to conditionally serialize. This is also one of the reasons I generally disagree with return/serialize entities directly; the entity structure and its representation outside of your application are coupled. If you are open to mapping the entities to DTOs you can very easily control what’s gets serialized in each use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to do this using JsonView or JsonFilter with Jackson. Another option would be to separate the concerns, i.e. use a DTO to control the serialized view of the entity. 
Here is a link to a tutorial on some of these Jackson features: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it’s due to the default Open Session in View. Starting with version 2.0

If you added below line in your application.properties configuration file, then it should work

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I wrote I tried this solution and with open-in-view false I get

    Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: .., could not initialize proxy - no SessioUnable to evaluate the expression 

On debug I see

Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception. 
for each list of children

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally have done it. I wrote a dedicated HQL for Parent without children.

```
    @Query("SELECT new Parent(a.parentId, a.name, a.address, a.city) FROM Parent a WHERE a.otherId= :id")
List<Parent> findAllBySomeOtherIdWithoutChildren(@Param("id") Long id);
```

It looks like this is the fastest way for it. Thanks for all suggestions.